# How would you record votes using a python program?

Tags: python, html, survey

I have to make a survey using html and python. The html is finished but recording the answers to the survey using python does not work properly. I tried programming it such that when the radio buttons are checked the program will raise the number of votes, but I keep receiving a syntax error. I'm not quite sure how to work this all out. Help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: "I tried programming it" May we see?

Comment: what are the syntax errors? can you please share the code?

Answer (score 0):

well since yo showed no code try something like:

```
if selection1 == True
    sel1_votes+=1
if selection2 == True
    sel2_votes+=1
#etc
```

`selection1` being the voting button for the first selection and `sel1_votes` being the amount of votes for that selection

Answer (score 0):

Based on what serial said
Try putting that in a while loop such as

```
selecting = 1
while selecting == 1:
    if selection1 == True
        sel1_votes+=1
        selecting = selecting + 1
    if selection2 == True
        sel2_votes+=1
        selecting = selecting + 1
```

etc